How to order class attributes before methods with autoclass in sphinx-docs?
When generating the class docs using .. autoclass:: I tried with the flag autodoc_member_order = 'groupwise'. However, the methods are coming above class attributes.
Any suggestions on how to order class attributes above class methods?
